# magento 1.9 CE error when duplicating a product

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, sql

When I use the method to duplicate an object sometimes I get this error message, the product is created:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-0-0-1-4-24884-0' for key 'KEY', query was: INSERT INTO `etpq_catalogrule_product` (`rule_id`,`from_time`,`to_time`,`website_id`,`customer_group_id`,`product_id`,`action_operator`,`action_amount`,`action_stop`,`sort_order`,`sub_simple_action`,`sub_discount_amount`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

This is how I duplicate a product and I associate it to a configurable:

```
try {
    $configurable = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/product')->load( '2456' );
    $childIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getChildrenIds( $configurable->getId() )[0];
    $id= $childIds[0];
    //duplicate this product
    $child = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/product' )->load( $id );
    //echo 'chid: ' . $child->getId() . '<br />';

    $duplicated = $child->duplicate();
    // reload duplicated
    $duplicated = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/product' )->load( $duplicated->getId() );
    $duplicated
        ->setDescription( 'dummy' )
        ->setName( 'dummy - ' . $configurable->getName() )
        ->setTitle( 'dummy - ' . $configurable->getName() )
        ->setStatus( Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED )
        ->setSku( 'dummy-' . $configurable->getSku() );
    $duplicated->save();

    $childIds[] = $duplicated->getId();
    Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')->saveProducts( $configurable, $childIds );
    $configurable->setData( 'status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED );
    $configurable->getResource()->saveAttribute( $configurable, 'status' ); 
    return TRUE;
}
catch ( Exception $e ) {
    Mage::log( $e->getMessage() );
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: This issue may be similar to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232992/magento-integrity-constraint-violation-1062-duplicate-entry-error-when-saving-s

The product you are trying to duplicate may have a catalog rule on it , the catalogrule_product table has a similar unique key setup, so you may need to copy the catalog rule into the new product before saving.

Comment: I'm using this method to save the product and it seems it works:

$duplicated->getResource()->save( $duplicated );